# How to Call Matlab Functions from C++

Tags: c++, c, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-engine

I want to call MATLAB function in my C++ project.

I'm using Matlab R2010a and Visual Studio 2010

First I created a simple matlab function:

```
function y = foo(x)
    y = x+1;
```

and then I used matlab compiler to compile this function using matlab GUI compiler (File-> new -> Deployment Project and then choose C++ shared Library).  It produces this files 2 folders: distrib and src.

distrib contains:

1. foo.dll
2. foo.h
3. foo.lib

src contains :

1. foo.cpp
2. foo.dll
3. foo.exp
4. foo.exports
5. foo.h
6. foo.lib
7. foo_mcc_component_data.c

I want to use this file in a C++ application.  I tried many times and I didn't find a way.  All the ways I found over the internet are using old matlab compiler which produces different files or works on an old version of visual studio.

So please could anyone help me?

What must I do?  What files/references must I add and to where?  What paths must I define?

Answer (score 12):

maybe it is too late but for the future.

Include `foo.h`.

Add *C/C++-General-Additional Include Directories* the way to the matlab headers (`C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2009b\extern\include`).

Add `foo.lib`, `mclmcrrt.lib` and `mclcommain.lib` for *Linker in Additional Dependencies*.

For *linker* in *Additional Library Directories* show the way to your matlab libs(`C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2009b\extern\lib\win32\microsoft` for 32bit ver (matlab and VS versions should be the same. I had to install the second Matlab 32bit version.)).

I added the way to the `foo.lib` in my system path.

Before using your library `foo.dll`, you should initialize MCR and library function.

```
mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0);
fooInitialize();
```

After using don't forget:

```
mclTerminateApplication();
fooTerminate();
```

And some demonstration code, looks like:

```
int num = 1;
double numbrIn = 1.5;
std::cout<<"now we have " << numbrIn << std::endl;
mwArray array_in(num, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
array_in.SetData(&numbrIn,num);
mwArray array_out;
foo(1, array_out, array_in);
array_out.GetData(&numbrIn, num);
std::cout<<"now we have " << numbrIn << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

The files `foo.h` and `foo.lib` will be required to compile your application.  The `foo.dll` file will need to be shipped with your resulting application, usually in the same directory.

If you put the `foo.h` file in the same directory as your source files, you won't need to do anything special to `#include "foo.h"`.  You can also add the direct path to `foo.lib` in the external linker dependencies.

If you want to store these files outside of your project folder and/or re-use these files in other applications, you can read up on [VC++ Directories, Projects and Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9az1d21.aspx).

**Edit**: You probably also need to add the MATLAB libraries to your include and library paths.  Check out the MathWorks support solution [Why do I receive the error 'Could not find include file "mclmcrrt.h"' when trying to compile a stand-alone application?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5VS830/index.html?product=CO&solution=1-5VS830)

Comment: I added only foo.h in the header files and i created a main.cpp file and i included foo.h and i open project properties and i go to linker and i added in the additional dependencies foo.lib

and when in build the project it gives me error that it can't open this two source files
#include "mclmcrrt.h"
#include "mclcppclass.h"
its located in foo.h

Could you help me?